# What is the epoch of CLOCK_TAI?

Tags: c, linux, time, posix, tai-time

Since Linux kernel version 3.10, the function `clock_gettime()` now accept `CLOCK_TAI`.

I didn't manage to find a detailed description of this clock. What is its epoch ?

**EDIT 1**: Just compared the output of CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_TAI on my Linux 3.19 OS and it returns the exact same value (1442582497) !? Is CLOCK_REALTIME decremented at leap seconds ?

**EDIT 2**: According to [this article](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/06/01/five-different-ways-handle-leap-seconds-ntp/), the difference between CLOCK_TAI and the (badly named) CLOCK_REALTIME should be the number of leap seconds.

**EDIT 3**: The reason `CLOCK_TAI` and `CLOCK_REALTIME` are the same time is explained in the article referenced in Edit 2. The emphasis is by me.

> For applications where it would be possible to work with TAI time instead of UTC, the kernel provides a special CLOCK_TAI clock which does include leap seconds and doesn’t need to be corrected after leap second, avoiding the problem with backward jump in the time entirely. It’s implemented as a clock running at a fixed integral offset to CLOCK_REALTIME, which is atomically incremented by 1 when the CLOCK_REALTIME clock is stepped back on leap second. It was introduced in the Linux kernel version 3.10 and is available with the kernels shipped in RHEL7. **Please note that the offset from CLOCK_REALTIME is initialized on boot to zero and neither ntpd nor chronyd set it by default to the correct value (currently 35).** Switching to CLOCK_TAI in applications would of course require modifications to the code and possibly also all protocols that use the Unix representation of time.

**Edit 4** : [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/675644/15352) obtained on Ask Ubuntu clarifies everything.

Comment: It might not have one, like `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time ?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The TAI must have an epoch to be able to convert it into gregorian format.

Comment: @chmike I posted my answer here,wrt [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675622/why-clock-tai-and-clock-realtime-returns-the-same-value/675644#675644)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CLOCK_TAI is basically designed as CLOCK_REALTIME(UTC) + tai_offset.
```

So the usec/nsec portion of a timeval/timespec should be identical.

```
CLOCK_MONOTONIC: Zeroed at boot.  

CLOCK_TAI = CLOCK_MONOTONIC + tai_mon_offset    

CLOCK_REALTIME(UTC) = CLOCK_TAI - tai_utc_offset
```

But due to performance concerns (CLOCK_REALTIME is what applications
hammer the most), in Linux we actually structure it as:

```
CLOCK_REALTIME: Initialized at boot from RTC  
CLOCK_MONOTONIC: CLOCK_REALTIME - wall_to_monotonic  
CLOCK_TAI: CLOCK_REALTIME + tai_offset
```

So `CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_TAI return the same because the kernel parameter tai_offset is zero.`

Check by using `adjtimex(timex tmx)` and read the value. I think that `ntpd` will set it if it is new enough (`>4.2.6`) and has a leap second file. It may also be able to get it from upstream servers but I haven't been able to verify. The call `adjtimex()` can set `tai_offset` manually when run as root.

My reference [here](http://allanswershere.com/question/29355406/how-to-obtain-current-tai-time) and [here](http://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/hackers/2013-October/006130.html)